# Extracting data from xml file using xmllint

Tags: xml-parsing, extract, xmllint

I have a small [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) document from which I need to extract some values using xmllint. I am able to navigate through the xml hierarchy using `xmllint --shell xmlfilename` command.

But I am unable to extract the values. I don't want to use a `grep /` any pattern matching command, as that is already done and is a success.

I would appreciate any help regarding the [xmlliint](/questions/tagged/xmlliint).

Here is my document in `png` format. I want to extract the `300$` and `500$` (the `value`).

```xml
<?xml version="1`.`0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<adi>
    <asset>
        <electronics item="Mobile" name="Nokia" value="300$" />
        <electronics item="Mobile" name="Sony" value="500$" />
    </asset>
</adi>
```

Another doubt is, are the two sets, the different representation of same [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) ?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0 encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<adi>
    <asset>
        <electronics>
            <item> Mobile </item>
            <name>Nokia</name>
            <value>300$</value>
        </electronics>
        <electronics>
            <item> Mobile </item>
            <name>Sony</name>
            <value>500$</value>
        </electronics>
    </asset>
</adi>
```

Comment: look at xmlstarlet for this sort of task. Or note the lower follwer counts on your tags (when you rollover them) and add a tag for xml or xmlstarlet. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to your second question, those two snippets do *not* represent the same XML content. Attributes and child elements are not equivalent. A child element can be the root element of some arbitrary XML tree, but attributes are atomic.

E.g., I could modify the second snippet like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0 encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<adi>
    <asset>
        <electronics>
            <item>
               Mobile
               <sub-item>Phone</sub-item>
            </item>
            <name>Nokia</name>
            <value>300$</value>
        </electronics>
        <electronics>
            <item> Mobile </item>
            <name>Sony</name>
            <value>500$</value>
        </electronics>
    </asset>
</adi>
```

where I have added `<sub-item>Phone</sub-item>` to the first `<item>` element.
However, there's no equivalent if `item` is an attribute instead, as in the first snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Late but while searches for the tag *xmllint* match the first page, I answer you now ;)

use --xpath instead of --xpath like below

```
xmllint --xpath '//electronics/value/text()' second-xml_file.xml
```

Comment: xpath work, that's the xml source that is broken. See the missing `"` on the first line.

Comment: its saying that --xpath option is not available in xmllint

Comment: Use path instead of xpath in the above command.                                        xmllint --path '//electronics/value/text()' second-xml_file.xml